# Limit to number of HTTPService calls that can be made at once

Tags: apache-flex, httpservice

I have 5 Cairngorm Events that I am dispatching at the same time(one right after the other)  - all of which call a separate HTTP Service. This works fine when I run the application locally however when I deploy my project to a Glassfish server, it only works intermittently, with the app hanging when it doesn't work.

My temporary work around to this is to chain some of the events together so less call are going out at once, but I don't really like this as a viable solution because it slows down performance.

Is there a maximum number of HTTPService requests that Flex can make at once before it hangs?

Comment: I think there are no official limit, but could you post client/server code runnable sources, please?

Answer (score 1):

It is a browser limitation - you cannot run more than X parallel requests in parallel. X is 2 in case of IE6 and 7, and 6 for Firefox3.